# paypal rest payment success but no histroy

Tags: paypal

use paypal rest api for payment, and return back paymentId & payer_id, but no payment history in my paypal account, how to query detail with paymentId or payer_id， my develop sdk is ruby.

here is the code

```
def paypal_service booking
  house =  booking.house
  house_info = "#{house.house_type} - #{house.category}"

  @payment = Payment.new({
    :intent =>  "sale",

    :payer =>  {
      :payment_method =>  "paypal" },

    :redirect_urls => {
      :return_url => "#{@app_url}/bookings/#{booking.out_trade_no}/return",
      :cancel_url => "#{@app_url}/bookings/#{booking.out_trade_no}/cancel" },

    :transactions =>  [{

      :item_list => {
        :items => [{
          :name => "#{house_info}",
          :sku => "xxx-#{house.id}",
          :price => "1", #todo just for test
          :currency => 'USD',
          :quantity => 1 }]},

        :amount =>  {
          :total =>  "1",
          :currency =>  'USD' },
        :description =>  house.title }]})

  if @payment.create
    @redirect_url = @payment.links.find{|v| v.method == "REDIRECT" }.href
    logger.info "Payment[#{@payment.id}]"
    logger.info "Redirect: #{@redirect_url}"

    return @redirect_url
  else
    logger.error @payment.error.inspect
  end
end
```

Comment: You show cod for creating the payment, but not for executing the payment.  The payment does not happen until you post to payment/execute.

Comment: thanks for you help, my problem, not execute the payment